# How to populate data in docusign template document from React.js front end?

Tags: reactjs, docusignapi

I need to populate some field in one of template document from client side React.js form. Is there any particular DocuSign eSignature API to which I can post my form data to fill the document on form submission? Also how the field mapping can be done between document and form fields?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/ shows how to do this in various programaing languges.

In order to do that from the client app such as react.js you will need to [set up CORS](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/single-page-applications-cors/).

The code to map values to tabs in your envelope created from template looks like this:

```
let list1 = docusign.List.constructFromObject({
        value: "green", documentId: "1", pageNumber: "1", tabLabel: "list"});

    // Checkboxes
    let check1 = docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
            tabLabel: 'ckAuthorization', selected: "true"})
      , check3 = docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
            tabLabel: 'ckAgreement', selected: "true"});
    // The NOde.js SDK has a bug so it cannot create a Number tab at this time.
    //number1 = docusign.Number.constructFromObject({
    //    tabLabel: "numbersOnly", value: '54321'});
    let radioGroup = docusign.RadioGroup.constructFromObject({
            groupName: "radio1",
            // You only need to provide the radio entry for the entry you're selecting
            radios:
                [docusign.Radio.constructFromObject({value: "white", selected: "true"})]
    });
    let text = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
            tabLabel: "text", value: "Jabberwocky!"});

    // We can also add a new tab (field) to the ones already in the template:
    let textExtra = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
            document_id: "1", page_number: "1",
            x_position: "280", y_position: "172",
            font: "helvetica", font_size: "size14", tab_label: "added text field",
            height: "23", width: "84", required: "false",
            bold: 'true', value: args.signerName,
            locked: 'false', tab_id: 'name'});

    // Pull together the existing and new tabs in a Tabs object:
    let tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
        checkboxTabs: [check1, check3], // numberTabs: [number1],
        radioGroupTabs: [radioGroup], textTabs: [text, textExtra],
        listTabs: [list1]
    });
    // Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
    // to the template
    let signer = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
            email: args.signerEmail, name: args.signerName,
            roleName: 'signer',
            clientUserId: args.signerClientId, // change the signer to be embedded
            tabs: tabs // Set tab values
    });
    // Create a cc template role.
    let cc = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
            email: args.ccEmail, name: args.ccName,
            roleName: 'cc'
    });
    // Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
    envelopeDefinition.templateRoles = [signer, cc];
    // Create an envelope custom field to save the our application's
    // data about the envelope
    let customField = docusign.TextCustomField.constructFromObject({
            name: 'app metadata item',
            required: 'false',
            show: 'true', // Yes, include in the CoC
            value: '1234567'})
      , customFields = docusign.CustomFields.constructFromObject({
            textCustomFields: [customField]});
    envelopeDefinition.customFields = customFields;

    return envelopeDefinition;
```